# Understanding disassembler: See how many bytes are used for add

Tags: gcc, assembly, compiler-construction, disassembly, att

I disassembled a program (with `objdump -d a.out`) and now I would like understand what the different sections in a line like

```
400586:       48 83 c4 08             add    $0x8,%rsp
```

stand for. More specifically I would like to know how you can see how many bytes are used for adding two registers. My idea was that the `0x8` in `add $0x8,%rsp`, which is 8 in decimal gives me 2 * 4 so 2 bytes for adding 2 registers. Is that correct?

PS: compiler is gcc, OS is suse linux

Comment: you should read Intel manual. It listed all instructions and opcodes

Comment: there are different opcodes for different instruction form. And operations on AX have special shorter opcodes

Comment: Save yourself a lot of time. Get a good book on x86 assembly language and study it.  This instruction does not add two registers.  It adds an immediate value of 8 to the stack pointer. Nearly all x86 instructions allow different addressing modes (register, indexed, index-offset, base-index-offest, direct, etc.).  The number of bytes in an `add` instruction depend on how its operands are addressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the second column you see `48 83 c4 08`. Every two-digit hex-number stands for one byte, so the amount of bytes is four. The last `08` correlates to `$0x8`, the other three bytes are the machine code for "add an 8-bit constant to RSP" (for pedantic editors: Intel writes its registers upper case). It's quite difficult to deconstruct the machine code, but your assumption is completely wrong.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! So if I have something like: 40048a:       48 01 d0                add    %rdx,%rax - (that is adding two registers, isn't it?) the amount of bytes used is three?

Comment: @eva: `add %rdx,%rax`: add RDX to RAX (result in RAX). The amount is three, you've got it :-)